# Return value from struct when used

Tags: swift, struct, swift-playground

I am quite new to Swift and I am learning about `struct`s. However, I have a problem which might sound obvious, but I'm not sure how to do it. I am doing all this in the playground.

I have a `struct` called `Colour`, where I create an RGB colour type. I want to access its variables (e.g. by doing `yellow.red` which will read and write the variable to find the value of red in the colour yellow).

```
struct Colour {
    var red: Int
    var blue: Int
    var green: Int

    var rgb: [Int] // <- I don't want to have this variable, I want to make the struct Colour be this array

    init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue

        rgb = [red, green, blue]
    }
}
```

Call:

```
let red = Colour(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0) // Colour
red.red                                       // 255
red.green                                     // 0
red.blue                                      // 0

red                                           // Colour
red.rgb                                       // [255, 0, 0]
```

When I access `red`, I want it to automatically return the value of `red.rgb`, without the variable.

So how can I call `red` and return an `Array` with the value `[255, 0, 0]`?

**Notes:**

- A `get` or `set` cannot be implemented
- I cannot use `Colour` as a variable, as I need initialisation
- `return` keyword cannot be used, as `struct`s don't work in this way

**Edit**

Sorry for not making this clear enough. I was looking to return a `[Int]`, but it is clearly not worth what I was originally trying.

The solutions with the protocols definitely work if you want to return a string, which is why I have accepted an answer.

**Edit 2**

We now have a working answer using `type alias`!

Comment: If you just use `red`, do you want the `[255, 0, 0]` as an actual `[Int]` or are you just looking for the output of `red` to show the three color components instead of the text `Colour`? Show a more specific example of how you plan to use this result.

Comment: @rmaddy When I want red, as specified towards the end, I want to return the actual Int array of `[255, 0, 0]`

Comment: So if you have the line `let result = red`, you expect `result` to be an `[Int]`. Is that a correct assessment of what you want? Please update your question making that clear.

Comment: @rmaddy It is of type `[Int]`, yes

Comment: Side note: `rgb` would be better as a computed property: `var rgb: [Int] { return [red, green, blue] }`

Comment: @Alexander I think you might be right - will be much easier than protocols...

Comment: I have read your question two times but yet again do not understand what you want. Could you explain further and use expressive variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can define a `typealias` Colour. This might be a little more efficient, but perhaps not as type safe.

See code:

```
typealias Colour = [Int]

extension Array where Element == Int {

    init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        self = [red, green, blue]
    }

    var red: Int { return self.count > 0 ? self[0] : 0 }
    var green: Int { return self.count > 1 ? self[1] : 0 }
    var blue: Int { return self.count > 2 ? self[2] : 0 }

}
```

Example Usage:

```
let red = Colour(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0) // Colour
red.red                                       // 255
red.green                                     // 0
red.blue                                      // 0

red                                           // [255, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Wow! That actually worked, like what I was expecting! Please can you just tell me why you used an extension to Array and have a where clause? Just a newbie, so just need some comments :) Thanks

Comment: The Colour type alias is just an Array of Int values. Swift lets you extend built-in types, including Array. The where clause constrains the extension to only Arrays of Int values.

Comment: If you wanna go for type safety, but keep a `Collection` structure, you could easily create a custom `Collection` that can only be indexed using a `enum RGB {case red,green,blue}`, can only be instantiated with 3 values and is hence can never result in an out of bounds exception.

Comment: While this answer has some potential, try code such as: `let c: Colour = [1,2]; print(c.blue)`. Boom!

Comment: Agree. I would not choose this pattern for production software, but it does fit the narrow criteria which I assume is from a class project.

Comment: Minimal safety for accessors has been added above.

Answer (score 2):

`red` is a `Colour`. There's nothing you can do to change that. Nothing you do can make `red` act directly as a `[Int]` containing the `red`, `green`, and `blue` components.

There are different things you can do, depending on what your actual needs are. For example, if you just want it to act like an `[Int]` for the sake of printing like `[255, 0, 0]`, then you can override `var description: String` and conform to [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible).

The sort of feature you're looking for is like [C++'s user-defined conversion operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). These can be really cool, but can also easily lead to very unclear code. Swift opts for explicitly expressing such conversions, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I receive the error `error: MyPlayground.playground:15:5: error: return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`. I conformed to the protocol and added the line you suggested

Comment: @George_E_2 Well you have to implement it. Look at the example in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

Comment: I am not looking to return a string, so instead, I might just use the rgb property I created - seems like the easiest way. Thank you for helping anyway!

Comment: @George_E_2 As my answer stated "depending on what your actual needs are". The suggestion to add a `description` to your struct assumed that your motivation to have an `[Int]` was for the purposes of printing like `[255, 0, 0]`, which doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @George_E_2 You should make it  a computed property, at least. And what exactly do you need it as an array for?

Comment: I don't **specifically** need the array for anything, I am just learning from the Apple docs and decided to try this out

Comment: @George_E_2 Ah, I see. So yeah, can't do implicit conversion like this, in Swift, because it goes against clarity

Answer (score 1):

Swift has a Protocol called `CustomDebugStringConvertible` that should accomplish what you're looking for. After declaring that your struct adopts that Protocol, just implement the `debugDescription` variable in your code.

See update code:

```
struct Colour: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var red: Int
    var green: Int
    var blue: Int

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "\(array)"
    }

    var array: [Int] {
        return [red, green, blue]
    }

    init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let red = Colour(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0) // Colour
red.red                                       // 255
red.green                                     // 0
red.blue                                      // 0

red                                           // "[255, 0, 0]"
red.array                                     // [255, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear enough in the question. I was looking to return a type `[Int]`. I will however accept these answers, as they are definitely viable for other users who just want a string

Comment: See my other answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a function such as `toArray()`

That could look something like this:

```
struct Colour {
  var red: Int
  var blue: Int
  var green: Int

  init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
    self.red = red
    self.green = green
    self.blue = blue
  }

  func toArray() -> [Int] {
    return [self.red, self.green, self.blue]
  }
}
```

Then, in your code, you can just use `let rgbArray = MyColour.toArray()`

Also, I would advise against storing the same underlying data twice, such as with your rgb variable. If you change the Colour.red variable, that would mean your Colour.rgb value is not updated with that new value automatically and you suddenly get back values that you did not expect. With the function approach, you won't have that problem.

Comment: I don't want to go with a function approach, I was just looking for the return from the variable `red`. There is an answer using `type alias` which works as expected, but thank you anyways!

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't want to use a function? It's really the most straightforward way...

Comment: It is definitely a good answer, but here I just preferred to not use any functions or variables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the `Colour` type a custom collection, enabling you to use it like an `Array` but make it type-safe at the same time, you can create a custom `struct` and make it conform to `Collection`. You can create an `RGB` `enum` that can be used for indexing the custom collection and a failable initializer that ensures you can only create a `Colour` instance with valid RGB values.

```
struct Colour: Collection, RandomAccessCollection {
    // Custom enum used for indexing Colour
    enum RGB: Int, Hashable, Comparable, Strideable {
        case red, green ,blue

        // Find the last existing rawValue, assumes that the first case has rawValue 0 and that rawValues are incremented by 1
        static let maxRawValue: RGB.RawValue = {
            var maxRawVal = 0
            while RGB(rawValue: maxRawVal) != nil {
                maxRawVal += 1
            }
            return maxRawVal
        }()

        static let rawValues: [RGB.RawValue] = {
            var rawValues = [RGB.RawValue]()
            var currentRawValue = 0
            while RGB(rawValue: currentRawValue) != nil {
                rawValues.append(currentRawValue)
                currentRawValue += 1
            }
            return rawValues
        }()

        static func <(lhs: RGB, rhs: RGB) -> Bool {
            return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
        }

        typealias Stride = Int
        func distance(to other: RGB) -> RGB.Stride {
            return self.rawValue - other.rawValue
        }

        func advanced(by n: RGB.Stride) -> RGB {
            return RGB(rawValue: (self.rawValue+n)%RGB.maxRawValue)!
        }
    }
    typealias Element = Int
    typealias Index = RGB

    //Private backing Array
    private var components:[Element] = Array<Element>.init(repeating: Element.init(), count: RGB.rawValues.count)
    var startIndex: Colour.Index {
        return RGB(rawValue: components.startIndex)!
    }
    var endIndex: Colour.Index {
        return RGB(rawValue: components.endIndex)!
    }

    subscript (position: Index) -> Element {
        get {
            return components[position.rawValue]
        }
        set {
            components[position.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        return Index(rawValue: components.index(after: i.rawValue))!
    }
    private init(){}
    //Failable initializer that makes sure only a 3 element Array can be used as an input and that each element is in the valid RGB color code range
    init?<C:Collection>(_ collection:C) where C.Element == Element, C.Index == Index.RawValue {
        guard collection.indices.map({$0}) == RGB.rawValues else {return nil}
        for (index, element) in collection.enumerated() {
            guard element <= 255 && element >= 0 else {return nil}
            self.components[index] = element
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use your custom collection safely:

```
let red = Colour([255,0,0]) // Colour
let invalidColour = Colour([255]) // nil
let invalidColour2 = Colour([255,2,3,4]) // nil
let invalidColour3 = Colour([255,-1,256]) // nil
let randomColour = Colour([1,5,231]) // Colour
// you can use the RGB cases to access the respective values in the collection
randomColour?[.red] // 1
```